# Scala Play Forms allowing invalid emails

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I am trying to validate that an email is valid. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
  private val emailForm =
    Form(mapping("id" -> optional(of[Long]), "email" -> email)(Email.apply _)(Email.unapply _))


  def submit = Action { implicit request =>
    emailForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => { // this code is never hit, even if I leave the textbox blank
        Ok(views.html.masterpage("Home")(views.html.landingPage(formWithErrors, "There was an error on your form")))
      }, email => {

          emailDAO ! EmailDAO.Create(email)
        Ok(views.html.masterpage("Thank you")(views.html.thankyou("Thank you for subscribing to our mailing list!")))
      })
}
```

Comment: In your form def... `"email" -> email.verifying(emailAddress)` should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe... you need to add a validation in your form definition.

```
private val emailForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "id" -> optional( of[ Long ] ),
    "email" -> email.verifying( emailAddress )
  )( Email.apply _ )( Email.unapply _ )
)
```

Comment: `not found: value emailAddress` is the error I received

Comment: `import play.api.data.validation.Constraints._`

Comment: Now my form is always erroring out, even if I pass in a valid email address, do you have any idea why this could be the case?

Comment: Well... I did the same... and I am not getting any errors for valid email addresses... and it is detecting invalid email addresses perfectly. You can try just `import play.api.data.validation.Constraints.emailAddress` instead of `import play.api.data.validation.Constraints._`... may be you have some conflict with one of methods in `play.api.data.validation.Constraints`.

Comment: Does the `name` field for the html element play a role in matching the form? Here is how my html element is defined `<input type="text" id="Email Address" name="Email Address" value="">`

Comment: Here is how it is defined with Play's template engine `@helper.inputText(field=email("Email Address"))`

Comment: Yes the name field is very important. That's how the form element mapped to the value. So... make sure input names are same as field names in your form. In this case make it `"email"`.